# Prove the existence of a special diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathcal{S}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, stereographic-projections

I have the following exercise which I cannot solve:

Show that there exists a smooth map $\mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathcal{S}^m$ onto the m-sphere such that the open ball $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^m | \: \| x\|_{2} < 1 \}$ is mapped diffeomorphically onto the complement $\mathcal{S}^m \setminus \{s\}$ of a point $s \in \mathcal{S}^m$ and its exterior $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^m | \: \|x\|_{2} \geq 1 \}$ is mapped constantly to s.

If anyone has an idea for that part that would be really helpful.

What I already tried:
We can argue with symmetry so it's obvious we only need to construct such a map for s equal the south pole of the sphere.
I think the stereographic-projection should work as a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathcal{S}\setminus \{s\}$. But it does not map the exterior $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^m | \: \|x\|_{2} \geq 1 \}$ entirely to the point s.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please make the effort to type out the actual specific question and to tell us what you've tried to do. Posting an image with zero effort — and expecting us to do your homework for you — is beyond rude.

Comment: I am awfully Sorry Ted. I did not wish to offend anyone here. This is just my first post in this forum. The one where I asked/answered questions before it was just common to post the pictures. And I don't expect anything. If you want to help I would be very grateful.

Comment: A ball is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^m$. You will want to use an appropriate bump function and work in a chart centered at infinity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am familiar with bump-functions but unfortunately don't know what a "chart centered at infinity" is. I also couldn't find the concept in Lee/Loring. Could you explain what that is ? Or maybe give a reference ? That would be great :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Here are some hints/suggestions: (i) Stereographic projection from a point on the sphere maps the entire Cartesian space to the complement of a point, so that's not quite going to work. (ii) Can you map the unit ball diffeomorphically to the complement of a point ignoring smooth extendability to the exterior? (iii) Can you make everything work if $m = 1$ using Ted's hint about smooth bump functions? (Apropos of nothing, the second author's name is _Tu_. :)

Comment: Hey Andrew, thank you for your comment. I think I managed to do the ii) part. First as a map $(x,y,0) \mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2)}$ from the ball to the upper half-sphere. And then using spherical coords $\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}), \: \phi \in (0, \pi)$ I mapped $\theta \mapsto 2*\theta$ which should give me the whole sphere. I am just not sure about the strip $(-\frac{\pi}{2},0) \times \{\pi\}$. Maybe I need to use two charts here and show that the map agrees there ?

Comment: In the case m = 1 I get after mapping to the half-space,
$\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(x,y) = (\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$. Again let $\theta \mapsto 2*\theta$.
So overall a map $x \mapsto (\sin(\arctan{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}),\cos(\arctan{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}))$. Outside of (-1,1) I would like everything to be mapped to (-1,0). but can I just extend the arctan "smoothly" to infinity ?